# Opportunistic CIFS protocol version (minimal version) selection based on connecting client or share?

Tags: ubuntu, samba, cifs, samba4

### Question(s)

- How - if at all - can I configure a client-specific or share-specific exception, allowing SMB1?
- I understand the security risk with enabling SMB1 and therefore would like to minimize the attack surface. As long as there are *exclusively* shares configured allowing this sort of guest access, does it make a difference at whether I enable SMB1 or not?

### Current situation

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 box with Samba 4.11.6-Ubuntu (`2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.3`) configured to accept connections to a particular share from anonymous connecting users (`security = user` with `map to guest = bad password` and at the share level `guest only = yes` and `guest ok = yes`).

This works fine from other Ubuntu machines. It does *not* work from an [Android app called X-plore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en). The app will fail with the error message:

> java.io.IOException: This client does not support the negotiated dialect.

There is a similarly configured Ubuntu 18.04 in my network, which has Samba 4.7.6-Ubuntu (`2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17`) configured in a similar fashion to the above server.

This also works fine from other Ubuntu machines (no matter whether newer or older Samba is used) *and* it does work from said Android app X-plore.

Okay, so that suggests that the version difference between 4.7.6 and 4.11.6 is the cause of the issue here. The differences in the `smb.conf` boil down to path differences and differences based on expanded variables (server name and such, e.g. `%h`), so I can rule that out with high certainty.

The Android app reports `SMB1` after connecting successfully to the Samba 4.7.6 server. So [*this* would seem to be a likely cause for the issue](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_4.11_Features_added/changed#SMB1_is_disabled_by_default) with the 4.11.6 version:

> #### SMB1 is disabled by default
>
> The defaults of 'client min protocol' and
> 'server min protocol' have been changed to SMB2_02.
>
> This means clients without support for SMB2 or SMB3 are no longer able
> to connect to smbd (by default).

The options for both of the remote Samba servers are given as follows in `/etc/fstab` (1. 18.04 2. 20.04):

```
$ awk '$3 ~ /cifs/ {print $4}' /etc/fstab|sed 's|'$(whoami)'|username|g'
nofail,user,guest,rw,uid=username,gid=username,forceuid,forcegid,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,_netdev,x-gvfs-hide,noauto,x-systemd.automount
nofail,user,guest,rw,uid=username,gid=username,forceuid,forcegid,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,_netdev,x-gvfs-hide,noauto,x-systemd.automount
```

... and the resulting mounted entries look like (same order as before):

```
$ awk '$3 ~ /cifs/ {print $4}' /proc/mounts 
rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,vers=3.1.1,sec=none,cache=strict,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=192.168.188.120,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1
rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,vers=3.1.1,sec=none,cache=strict,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=192.168.188.130,file_mode=0664,dir_mode=0775,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1
```

So evidently the protocol version 3.1.1 was selected *in both cases* by `mount.cifs` when negotiating the protocol version from some recent Ubuntu.

To support X-plore, it seems I need to enable SMB1. And that could be done from `smb.conf` with:

```
[global]
min protocol = SMB2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the answer over on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1240357/11316).

The gist is to add the following line on the server-side into `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
server min protocol = NT1
```

... followed by restarting `smbd` with either of the following (as superuser):

- `service smbd restart`
- `systemctl restart smbd.service`

After that the Android-side should be able to pick up on it. The difference is evidently the default minimum protocol version between the two Samba versions on 18.04 and 20.04.